# How to Get elements of a JSON Object in Javascript or JQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have a `JSON` object that I get from a `PHP` script using the `JSON_ENCODE` method.

My `JSON`:

```
[{"0":"1","field_name1":"1","1":"fieldValue1","field_name2":"fieldValue2","2":"0","field_name3":"fieldValue3","3":"1","field_name4":"fieldValue4"},
{"0":"11","field_name1":"1","1":"fieldValue1","field_name2":"fieldValue2","2":"0","field_name3":"fieldValue3","3":"1","field_name4":"fieldValue4"}]
```

I want to be able to access my field names and my field values via a loop for loop or via an each function , I can use `JavaScript` or `JQuery`, but I don't know how to do it, can you help me?

**EDIT** : I already tried the answer on this question : 
[Safely turning a JSON string into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

it gives me this output :

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Comment: have you parse your json?

Comment: You need to parse with the function "$.parseJSON" (jQuery) to have an array of Object (named obj for example). After you just need to iterate on this array (for or foreach loop) and access data like an array. For example with a for loop : obj[i]["field_name2"].

Comment: "it gives me this output" — That's the expected result of converting a JSON array or objects into a JavaScript array of objects and then converting to a plain string.

Comment: show what you tried or make a fiddle